# Is there a way to make something like a function template using C#?

Tags: c#

I have this code here:

```
        private void brandAnalytics_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string fileTARGET = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(openFileDialogTARGET.FileName);
                if (fileTARGET == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select a valid document.");
                }
                else if (driver == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please start the Edge Driver.");
                }
                else
                {
                  doStuff();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                brandAnalytics.BackColor = Color.White;
                button3.Text = "Error occured - check message box";
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

This is how I start pretty much every function, using try and catch. How do I save the repeatance, so that if I modify something, it changes in all functions? I can't think of anything, maybe someone has an idea? - is there such a thing as function templates?

Comment: Don't overabuse `try/catch`, it's made for things you can't control (network and such)

Comment: Closest thing would probably be a helper method to which you pass an `Action` delegate, that is then invoked inside such a try/catch block.

Comment: Instead of trying to replicate the code, reuse it. You could wrap your operation as an `Action` delegate and execute it, or you could create an `Operation` class that included not just the action but extra info like the data, descriptions etc that would allow you to display better notifications. Instead of manually setting the color, text and message for example, the UI controls could bind to the operation's properties.

Comment: By using either Action or an Operation class you could modify your notification code in a single place. If you wanted to add an animation, sound, a status bar, you'd only have to modify a single method

Comment: @Cid What would be your recommendation for handling unexpected errors?

Comment: @DeusTheTom by checking your inputs first

Comment: @Cid Will take that in mind, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would apply the Template Method pattern here:

https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/template-method

Basically your class

```
class Test
{
    private void brandAnalytics_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string fileTARGET = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(openFileDialogTARGET.FileName);
            if (fileTARGET == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a valid document.");
            }
            else if (driver == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please start the Edge Driver.");
            }
            else
            {
                doStuff();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            brandAnalytics.BackColor = Color.White;
            button3.Text = "Error occured - check message box";
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

will be split into 2 classes.

An abstract class:

```
// defines the template
abstract class Template
{
    private void brandAnalytics_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        try
        {
            if (EnsurePreconditions())
            {
                DoStuff();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HandleException(ex);
        }
    }

    private abstract bool EnsurePreconditions();
    private abstract void DoStuff();
    private abstract void HandleException(Exception ex);
}
```

And a concrete class:

```
// concrete test based on the template
class TestV2 : Template
{
    private override bool EnsurePreconditions()
    {
        string fileTARGET = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(openFileDialogTARGET.FileName);
        if (fileTARGET == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a valid document.");
            return false;
        }
        else if (driver == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please start the Edge Driver.");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private override void DoStuff()
    {
        // ommitted
    }

    private override void HandleException(Exception)
    {
        brandAnalytics.BackColor = Color.White;
        button3.Text = "Error occured - check message box";
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

and you can have as many concrete classes which are based on the template as you wish.

(I did not compile the code so there might be some syntax errors.)

Comment: Yep, would do the same.